# How to navigate to the page with Site ID, web id and list id instead of url

Tags: url, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

What’s the template of a page link? I don’t have full url but I only have site id, web id & list id. I want to go to the page.

To be specific. It’s a page in sharepoint

Comment: It sounds like you'd need to look up things is the database.  Do you have DB access?

Comment: Yes i have db access. But in the url bar, can i go directly to the sharepoint site with just site id, web id and list id? Without url

Comment: As per my knowledge, I'm afraid there is no way to access the page with just site id, web id and list id.

Answer (score 0):

With what you have, you could use PowerShell to get the site URL from the site ID. If you're on SP Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spsiteurl?view=sharepoint-server-ps

Or for SP Online:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps